# Sending a large amount of texts

Tags: python, cookies, html-parsing

So, here's my program. What it does is send me a text when a new pm appears on a forum I'm on. The problem is it doesn't send just one, it sends hundreds.

How do I fix this? I'm asuming a `break` statment but I wouldn't know how to word it.

```
import urllib2
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
webp=urllib2.urlopen("http://hackforums.net").read()
words = urllib2.urlopen("http://hackforums.net").read()

word = 'titled'
while True:
    for word in words:
        if word in words:
            ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
            AUTH_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"

            client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

            message = client.sms.messages.create(to="XXXto", from_="XXXfrom",
                body="You have a new PM")
```

Then I'm using :

```
import os
import time

while True:
    os.system("python newway.py")

print 'done'
```

to open it.

Comment: I kinda messed up copy and pasting the code but i think its still readable

Comment: Edit your existing question (or delete it); don't have 2 of the same question open.

Comment: It wouldnt let me edit it, cause i was a new member but i tried

Comment: You have an infinite loop (`while True`) that repeatedly checks if each character in a string is in that string (which, obviously, it is), and if so, sends a text message. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: Is this really your entire program?

Comment: Oh, in addition to my answer, note that you set word, and then you re-assign it (`for` loop), so the `if word in words` will always be true . . .

Comment: I tried putting the loop there so that it would keep checking if I had a new PM or not, I guess i didnt realize that it would keep sending texts.I tried removing the loop and it still sends a  lot of messages

Comment: You're sending one message for every character in the site's http response, each time through the loop. Additionally, it's unlikely you could even tell if you have a PM on the forum, since you don't try to login, but that's beside the point I think.

Comment: I wouldnt need to log in because im signed in and its cached right? and thanks for all the great answers

Comment: urllib2 doesn't hack your web browser and steal the cookies, I'm fairly certain.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the codeblock at top is `newway.py`, you have no check for whether the content is new or not, and the way you're calling it just keeps running it over and over.

You need to implement some way of tracking state (I'd suggest a file), and keep track of whether something is new or not, and only send messages when there is new content.